# ASP.NET WEB API Temp File operation Speed Up

Tags: asp.net, file, azure, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm hosting a WEB API App on Azure and I'm noticing some latency on a file operation.

What I'm doing is:

- Post File
- Write file on disk
- Execute operations on file

The problem is that it takes A LOT of time to simply "take" this file, this is my code:
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Test/Debug")]
        public async Task Debug()
        {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
                return Ok(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

As you can see it's really simple but it takes also 3 seconds to get the "postedFile" element.

Is there any way to optimize this? Any other way to increase performance? Is this file already stored in some temp dir so that I can access it without having to write him down and then delete it?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your goal? What you mean with "Execute operations on file"?

Comment: I'm running a process that runs something like my.exe input.file (console app)

Comment: I doubt this will work with API app, does it??

Comment: Yes, it's working. Quite well, the only bottleneck is this part of the method, the rest runs smoothly

Comment: ah okay, how big is the file you try to upload?

Comment: it goes from 300k to 5MB impacting obv on the method execution time

Comment: Hm okay.Sorry, I have no clue why it takes so long.